# The truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty a.bool() a.item() a.any() or a.all(). python

Tags: python

I have Dataframe which has a column which contain below value

```
DF1
    column
    Match
    Not_Match
    Not_Match
    Not_Match
    Not_Match
```

now I want to check condition, where if Df1[Column] == 'Not_Match', I will add one more column, Column2, and write 'Y' in that.

```
result3 = df3['Column1']=='Not_Match'
result3



if result3.all():
    df3['Column2'] = Match_Org
```

But in this case it is also taking 'Match' record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

`DF1.loc[(DF1['column1']=='Not_Match'), 'column2'] = 'Y'`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Column2'] = np.where(df.Column1 == 'Not_Match', 'Y', '')

     Column1    Column2
0      Match         
1  Not_Match        Y
2  Not_Match        Y
3  Not_Match        Y
4  Not_Match        Y
```